# not able to execute the script. After Maver-Test, browser is opening and below errors are showing in the console

Tags: java, websocket, automated-tests, httpurlconnection, ioexception

FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setUp
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:53584/devtools/browser/87a1db2f-4f8a-436c-a8ba-00d0d29e67d2
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'QA', ip: '192.168.0.38', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.(Connection.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:49)
at TestNG_MyFleetMan.MyFleetManAddBookings.setUp(MyFleetManAddBookings.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod tearDown
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDownAfterClass
SKIPPED: test
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:53584/devtools/browser/87a1db2f-4f8a-436c-a8ba-00d0d29e67d2
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
System info: host: 'QA', ip: '192.168.0.38', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '16.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.(NettyWebSocket.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.(Connection.java:77)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$2(ChromiumDriver.java:116)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:114)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:81)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:49)
at TestNG_MyFleetMan.MyFleetManAddBookings.setUp(MyFleetManAddBookings.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:700)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:527)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

I am performing MavenProject-Compile and then test. But showing org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException error